# Does Power BI have an equivalent of Metabase's X Ray feature (automatic insights and analysis)?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

One of the best parts of Metabase are X rays https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/exploration-and-organization/x-rays
Does Power BI have an equivalent? Eg give a tabular csv data source, and have Power BI generate graphs and insights automatically? Or do we have to clickety click together each report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's called "Quick Reports". Here's the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-quick-create-report

After you have saved the report, you can download the result as a .pbix file for further edits (including data integration) in Power BI Desktop, if needed.